# cloudera manager vs Apache

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera-manager

cloudera distribution is using cloudera manager for its automated installation and maintenance activities in a cluster like that Horton works distribution is using Ambari for same purpose in windows,can anyone tell what is the tool that Apache distribution is using for easy cluster installation and maintenance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned Cloudera Manager and Ambari provides 2 types of services, installation and then monitoring.

Ambari is open source apache project. Hortonworks provides support and services using their distribution.

You can also use puppet/chef for installation and use Ganglia for monitoring. Ambari internally uses those tools only.

Comment: Hi Mr.Viswanath, thanks for your reply , i am working on AWS  in command line and in apache distribution not horton works ,can you tell ,how can i use Apache ambari to configure automatic hadoop installation and monitoring in the AWS apache cluster

Comment: Automatic Hadoop installation can be done either by using emr console or command line. Monitoring can be done using ganglia.

Comment: Thanks mr viswanth ,i got one final doubt is ambari is used in horton works windows disto only or we can use that in any other distributions also...

Comment: Ambari is open source and part of all hortonworks distributions. You can manage non hortonworks using ambari. However it does not make sense to manage emr with ambari.